# Comparing growth estimates of multigroup growth curve model

Tags: multiple-comparisons, curve-fitting, latent-variable, growth-model

I have fitted a growth curve model to describe the trajectories of a variable in 4 groups across three assessment points. I am interested in doing some pair-wise comparisons of the slopes between some of the groups (Group A vs. Group B; Group C vs. Group D). I modeled all 6 groups together because fit indices for this model were much better than for the individual models and it made more sense conceptually as well. For the final model CFI was >0.95, RMSEA=.02, so overall it achieved very good fit to the data.

In order to facilitate model fit I had to constrain the variance of the slope in 1 of the 4 groups (Group C) to 0. Therefore, when I wanted to do group comparisons of the slopes I used independent sample t-tests for comparisons between Group A and Group B, but for the Group D I used a one sample-t-test and compared the slope against the slope value of Group C because in Group C the slope had a variance of 0.

Is there a better way to do this?

Note: The estimator I used for the growth curve model was robust to non-normality (MLR). I also decided not to compare slope differences by computing the difference in the chi-squares of nested models before and after fixing slopes to certain values for ease of understanding.